# error of connecting to remote IPython notebook server via ssh tunnel

Tags: ssh, server, jupyter-notebook

This is what I did:

```
   remote.server$ ipython notebook --no-browser --port=8889
   local$ ssh -v -N -L localhost:8888:localhost:8889 remote.server
```

Then I tried to launch it with `localhost:8888`. But on the remote server, there is this error:

```
[E 21:41:40.853 NotebookApp] Uncaught exception in write_error
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/zhxu5194/miniconda/envs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 976, in send_error
        self.write_error(status_code, **kwargs)
      File "/home/zhxu5194/miniconda/envs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/html/base/handlers.py", line 315, in write_error
        html = self.render_template('%s.html' % status_code, **ns)
      File "/home/zhxu5194/miniconda/envs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/html/base/handlers.py", line 253, in render_template
        ns.update(self.template_namespace)
      File "/home/zhxu5194/miniconda/envs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/html/base/handlers.py", line 263, in template_namespace
        logged_in=self.logged_in,
      File "/home/zhxu5194/miniconda/envs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/html/base/handlers.py", line 95, in logged_in
        user = self.get_current_user()
      File "/home/zhxu5194/miniconda/envs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/html/base/handlers.py", line 83, in get_current_user
        return self.login_handler.get_user(self)
      File "/home/zhxu5194/miniconda/envs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/html/auth/login.py", line 70, in get_user
        user_id = handler.get_secure_cookie(handler.cookie_name)
      File "/home/zhxu5194/miniconda/envs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 637, in get_secure_cookie
        self.require_setting("cookie_secret", "secure cookies")
      File "/home/zhxu5194/miniconda/envs/test/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1294, in require_setting
        "application to use %s" % (name, feature))
    Exception: You must define the 'cookie_secret' setting in your application to use secure cookies
```

And nothing showed up in the webpage. I did the same thing for another server and it worked. What is the problem for this server and how to fix it?

I am using virtual environment from miniconda. The versions are:

```
ipython                   3.2.1                    py27_0  
ipython-notebook          3.2.1                    py27_0  
jinja2                    2.7.3                    py27_1
tornado                   4.2                      py27_0  
zeromq                    4.0.5                         0
```

Comment: I am facing the same error even without the remote connection over ssh. I am using the Anaconda 3 python package and ipython version: `~/anaconda3/bin $ ./ipython --version
3.2.0`
Were you able to solve your problem?

Answer (score 3):

I've resolve this problem by reading Jupyter notebook official documents.

1.run

```
    jupyter notebook --generate-config
```

2.Then you will get

```
    jupyter_notebook_config.py
```

in '.jupyter'.

3.open

```
    jupyter_notebook_config.py
```

and write

```
    c.NotebookApp.cookie_secret = b'anything'
```

and it will work

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I looked into it a bit, seems like the automatic generation of the cookie secret somehow fails. What you can do to resolve this issue though, is to run:

```
ipython profile create
```

And then open this file (it shows you the exact location):

```
[ProfileCreate] Generating default config file: '/home/username/.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py'
...
```

with your favorite text editor.
At the end of the file append:

```
c.NotebookApp.cookie_secret = b"your secret that should not be on the internet"
```

And it should work.

If the browser still won't load the page, force refresh with <kbd>**Ctrl**</kbd>+<kbd>**F5**</kbd>